# Problems with Streams in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code for c# to read all the lines in TestFile.txt but when i finish reading i want to read it again and then put it in a string array (not a List) but when i try do that again it says that the file is already in use. I want to reset the stream or do something like sr.Close() because first time i read it i want to count how many lines are there in the Testfile.txt.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
           string line;
           while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
                     Console.WriteLine(line);
           }
}
```

I already tried to put after the while loop if(line == null) sr.Close() but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why loop twice over the file lines?

Comment: because i want to find out how many lines are there then make a string[] lines = new string[counter]

Comment: Why can't you use a `List<string>`? It can _easily_ be turned into an array.

Comment: That's really not how it should be done. Why don't you add them to a List<String> and then call .ToArray() on that when you're done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just read it into a `List<string>` and then build an array from that? Or more simply still, just call `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("TestFile.txt");
```

While you *could* reset the underlying stream and flush the buffer in the reader, I wouldn't do so - I'd just read it all once in a way that doesn't require you to know the size up-front.

(In fact, I'd try to use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]` anyway - they're generally more pleasant to use. Read [Eric Lippert's blog post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx) for more information.)

Comment: I agree with this completely. I was actually typing something very similar before Jon beat me to the punch (damn this community is fast).

Comment: You will have get up VERY early in morning to beat Jon to the punch: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by setting the `BaseStream` `Position` property to 0.

If you cannot (example would be a HttpWebResponse stream) then a good option would be to copy the stream to a `MemoryStream`...there you can set Position to 0 and restart the Stream as much as you want.

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
// later... after we read stuff
s.Position = 0;
```